# Multiple matrix products in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have two numpy arrays `A`, `B` of shapes `(k, m, n)` and `(k, n, l)` respectively. I am insterested in obtaining the following numpy array:

> `[A[0]@B[0], A[1]@B[1], ..., A[k-1]@B[k-1]]`

Clearly, I can do that with a for loop, but I would like to know if there is a more "numpy" way of doing it, which may perform better.

Thanks.

Comment: Does A@B` work?

Comment: Oh it does actually work!!! I can't believe I didn't try that. Please, post the comment as an answer

Comment: @hpaulj See above